# When it comes to build an error is thrown and i have no idea why

Tags: next.js, build

The problem is that any time I run `pnpm run build` an error is occurred, with no other information:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async GetData (C:\Users\Yassine98\Documents\APPS_EXPO\shadcn\.next\server\app\[slug]\page.js:374:26)
    at async GetImages (C:\Users\Yassine98\Documents\APPS_EXPO\shadcn\.next\server\app\[slug]\page.js:377:18)
info  - Generating static pages (4/4)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /[slug]/page: /[slug]
```

Note in `pnpm run dev` everything is good.

`[slug]/page.tsx`

```
import GetImages from "@/components/getImages"

type Params = {
  params: {
    slug: string
  }
}

function HomePage({ params }: Params) {
  const name = params.slug

  return (
    <div>
      {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
      <GetImages key={name} name={name} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

`GetImages.tsx`

```
/* eslint-disable tailwindcss/classnames-order */
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
/* eslint-disable-next-line tailwindcss/classnames-order */
import React from "react"

import DownButton from "./DownButton"

type Picture = {
  id: string
  imageUrl: string
}
const GetImages = async (name) => {
  async function GetData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SoufianeAmed/walee/main/${name.name}.json`
    )
    const response = await res.json()
    return response
  }
  const data = await GetData()
  console.log(data)

  return (
    <div className="m-10 bg-[#000212] md:masonry-2-col lg:masonry-3-col mx-auto ">
      {data.map((picture: Picture, idx: number) => {
        return (
          <div key={idx}>
            <div className="break-inside p-8 my-6  rounded-lg">
              <img
                src={picture.imageUrl}
                className="w-fit h-fit"
                alt="Wallee"
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <DownButton pic={picture.imageUrl} id={picture.id} />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default GetImages
```

Comment: Give it a try to replace `const name = params.slug` with `const name = params?.slug` and `${name.name}` with `${name?.name}` based on "Check for any code that assumes a prop is available, even when it might not be" suggestion on the doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Comment: @serdarsen Thanks Mate, but it still not working